# fine grained authentication in java

Tags: java, security, cryptography

It there a way to scope `javax.crypto.Cipher` calls within "trusted" part of the application? I would like to make sure `cipher.init` and `cipher.doFinal` happen only in "authorized" part of the program, so perhaps the fingerprint of these calls can be made a part of the key?

Comment: It's probably better to make sure to protect the Cipher and Key *instances* (make sure they are not reachable using reflection, for instance). Why would you disallow parts of the program to use encryption?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a policy file to enforce restrictions on certain methods: see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html for policy file detail. I'm not sure if the security manager can cover those methods though, but its worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate you would like to include the call path in the key. You can trivially restrict the the creation of valid keys by including a unique private parameter when you call the privileged functions, and incorporate it into the key.

This will remove the dependency on the code structure, while still linking the calling location to the authorisation. Of course, you now have another key component to secure.

The native Policy implementation may well be sufficient if you can trust the application deployments not to be subverted.